# Solving second-order nonlinear nonhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation I am trying to solve has the following form:

$$y'' + ay^3 = b$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constant coefficients. Although the equation seems trivial to solve, the little $b$ at the end drives me mad trying to solve it analytically. My question is this: is it possible to solve this equation exactly? If not, would it be possible to approximate it somehow (preferably still analytically)?

Thanks and my apologies if if a similar question has been asked already, I could not find any other questions similar enough to solve this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard trick in this situation is to multiply both sides by $y'$ and integrate:

$$\int y'' y' \ dx + a \int y^3 y' \ dx = \int b y' \ dx$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(y')^2 + \frac{a}{4} y^4 = by + C$$

Hence

$$y' = \pm \left(-\frac{a}{2}y^4 + by + C\right)^{1/2}$$

This equation is now separable. The next integral is not easy, but there exist analytic solutions for many values of $a$, $b$ and $C$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can see how the 'trick' works, but I can't quite see how the equation becomes separable after that, when all components on the RHS are contained within the root.

Comment: We have $dy/dx = f(y)$. Hence $$\int \frac{dy}{f(y)} = \int dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Good answer but you missed a "$2$" next to $b$, also you can do it this way:

$y'=p(y)$ thus $y''=p(y)p'$ then you get:

$p(y)p'+ay^3=b$, you can now separate variables and get to the DE that Simon S posted.